# Automating the pre-deployment approval in multi-repo CD pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Sorry for the long post.

I have a Git multi-repo environment. Each repo represents a project. Each repo has its own CI and CD pipeline. Pull requests merge code from topic branches to develop lines. From the develop branch, CD is triggered and DEV server gets updated with the newly built artifact. **When developers perform and validate their work on DEV, another server QA gets updated with the same artifact. This is the second stage of the CD pipeline.**

[image: CD pipeline]

In the customized Agile process, part of the flow is as follows for **User Story** work item type:

Deployed --> To Be Reviewed --> Reviewed by QA

Newly added code is committed and pushed with a **Task** work item. Hence, when a Task is under the state closed, this means the pull request is completed and the code is merged from the topic branch to the develop branch.

Tasks are the linked to a User Story (a task is a child).

For example, a user story (Story #A) is linked to 2 tasks (Task 1 and 2). Each task is related to a project (Project 1 and 2).

- When Task 1's pull request is completed, project 1's CI/CD is triggered and the code is deployed on DEV server. Task 1 gets status closed but Story #A's status remains Active since tasks 2 is not closed yet.
- When Task 2's pull request is completed, project 2's CI/CD is triggered and the code is deployed on DEV server. Task 2 gets status closed as well as Story #1's status changes to Deployed since task 1 and 2 are closed.

The above logic is being handled by a PowerShell script I wrote which gets executed in the CD pipeline for each project.

My question is how to trigger the deployment of stage QA of the CD pipeline for each project A and B after task 2 gets completed? The easiest solution is to add a **Pre-deployment approvals** before each QA stage for each pipeline but this is a long **manual** process taking into account daily hundreds of tasks are created and completed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding a **Query Work Items** deployment gate to QA stage.

[image]

First you need to create a query as shown in the figure below to get eligible tasks.

[image]

Then select this query in **Gate** and set the `Lower threshold` (The minimum number of matching workitems from the query) to `2`, so that if the number of closed tasks in query is `2`, perform deployment to QA stage. But, during each deployment to the QA stage, you need to modify the ID of the user story in the query, otherwise the previously closed items will also be queried, which will affect this deployment.

Comment: I did consider this however I modifying the ID in the query manually is not feasible. Moreover, many stories might have more than 2 tasks associated; the number is generic. Do you think there is a way to automate this? Thanks

Comment: As you mentioned in the question, you need to perform hundreds of deployments every day. Whether you judge by script or UI, you need to manually specify the item's ID. Otherwise, the items that were successfully executed before will affect this judgment, so this logic wants performing full automation should not be feasible.

Comment: I have a new idea. In release, we can get the relevant commit through the `BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` environment variable. According to this commit, we can track the task related to the pull request with rest api, and then judge the status of the task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am doing something similar to what you suggested, however I still cannot find a way to automate the Approve deployment for the QA stage. The aim is to make the second stage (QA) triggered without manual intervention.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not feasible to trigger the second stage without manual intervention in this case. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.